# I converted a UIWebView to a WKWebView, now EvaluateJavascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, xamarin, wkwebview

There is a UIWebView in my app that evaluated some javascript to load the webview with some HTML content. I converted the UIWebView to a WKWebView and now that javascript is not evaluating.

I have tried evaluating some much simpler javascript (e.g., setting a div to say "Hello, World!") and that worked. But when I switch to the javascript that was working in the UIWebView, nothing shows up.

```cs
        private void InitializeWebView()
        {
            webView = new WKWebView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
            View = webView;
            webView.LoadHtmlString(WebCollageHtml(), null);
        }

        private string WebCollageHtml()
        {
            return
            @"
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <script src='https://scontent.webcollage.net/api/v2/product-content'></script>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div id='wc-power-page'></div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            ";
        }

        private void LoadWebViewContent(string sku)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sku))
            {
                return;
            }

            string script = @"Webcollage.loadProductContent('elevatemarketplace', '7300039843', {'power-page': {autoPlayAndStop: true}});";

            webView.EvaluateJavaScript(script,null);
        }
```

I would expect that if evaluating some javascript worked in a UIWebView, it should also work in a WKWebView.

Comment: Does the html string works in UIWebView? When I use a UIWebview to load the string, I can see nothing on the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The html above doesn't show anything until the javascript is evaluated that sets the content in `<div id='wc-power-page'></div>`. I've updated the code above.

Comment: What is the sku there? I still can't make it work, can you provide a sample?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Sorry, here's an example sku: 7300039843

Comment: Still can't get it work and I get a null exception. If you can provide a sample would better.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I've updated the code above.